# split string according to limiting character with regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a problem where I need to build a Python dictionary with a given string.
The string has a certain pattern as follows:

```
string = 'streetName=BENEDITO DE PAULA, QD 03 LT 03, state=AM, complement=SJ BANDEIRANTES, number=4, country=BRA'
```

The split cannot be done by comma, because there is a comma in the middle of the text that needs to become a string.
I need the split to be done by generating the following list below so that later it becomes a dictionary
The keys of dictionary is separet per equal sinal (=) and value is subsequent text.

```
list = ['streetName=BENEDITO DE PAULA, QD 03 LT 03', 'state=AM', 'complement=SJ BANDEIRANTES', 'number=4', 'country=BRA']
```

So I need to generate a list from a regex that I believe should consider the text `(, TEXT=)`

Then I will generate a dictionary as follows

```
dict(v.split("=") for v in re.split("(REGEX)", string))
```

Was using the function below, but it does not solve the problem for this case

```
def convert_to_json(x):
    dic = dict(v.split("=") for v in x.split(","))
    return json.dumps({k.strip():v for (k,v) in dic.items()})
```

Comment: Assuming you know what words you need to check for that you would not like to split, you could use python's `endswith` function.  That is, split according to a comma, but then iterate back through that result list and join consecutive words with a comma if they end with a certain word, or contain a certain word, or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split on the pattern `\w+=`, since you know the keys don't include non-word characters, and capture the split characters. This would leave you with the trailing space and comma, but that's not too hard to clean up:

```
import re

string = 'streetName=BENEDITO DE PAULA, QD 03 LT 03, state=AM, complement=SJ BANDEIRANTES, number=4, country=BRA'

pairs = re.split(r'(\w+=)', string)[1:]   
[a + b.strip(', ') for a, b in zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2])]
```

Results in :

```
['streetName=BENEDITO DE PAULA, QD 03 LT 03',
 'state=AM',
 'complement=SJ BANDEIRANTES',
 'number=4',
 'country=BRA']
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex will be hard to write here, because greedy matching will match too many commas, and non-greedy matching will match too few commas. Instead, I would solve this by splitting the text by comma, then checking each substring to see if it contains an equals sign.

```
def convert_to_dict(s):
    raw_items = s.split(", ")
    items = []
    for item in raw_items:
        if "=" in item:
            items.append(item)
        elif len(items) > 0:
            items[-1] += ", " + item
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid string: dictionary keys cannot contain commas")
    result = {}
    for item in items:
        key, value = item.split("=", maxsplit=1)
        result[key] = value
    return result
```